# How to retrieve the desired field's value from a collection and store it's ID in another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I am using node js and mongodb. I have this this route code

```
router.get('/taglist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('tagcollection');
    collection.findOne({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('taglist', {
            "taglist" : docs
        });
    });
});
```

this is for getting all taglist from the database and the response rendering to `taglist.jade` which is given below-

```
extends layout

   block content
     h1.
         Tag List
     ul
         each tag, i in taglist
          li

                #{tag.tagname}= tag._id
```

Now I want to search a `tagname` which is already stored in my `taglist` collection and want to store that ID belonging to tagname which matched and store it in another collection.

Right now my code is just finding all the `tagname` and printing all the `tag_id` in browser. I am new in web application and just started with node and MongoDB.

**UPDATE**

first code getting all the `tagcollection` data and second one is displaying all the `id` of each document.but this is not what I am expecting.

I am explaining what I am expecting- 
let's suppose `tagcollection` contain 2 or more `documents`.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("ksjsed3cccjdkmx"),
    "tagname" : "dinner"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("skd9a93cccb8kdn"),
    "tagname" : "music"
}
```

and so on ...
first I want to search for `music` tag 
if I find `music` tag is available in my `tagcollection` then it will display `id` of `music` tag and store this `id` in new collection(say in `newtagcollection`)

Comment: Not very clear what are you trying to achieve, need more details...

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

router.js:

```
router.get('/searchtag/:tag', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.collection('tagcollection');
    collection.findOne({ tagname: req.params['tag'] }, function(e, result) {
        res.render('searchtag', { tag: result });
    });
});
```

searchtag.pug:

```
extends layout

  block content
    h1.
      Tag Search

    if tag
      p= tag.tagname + ' = ' + tag._id;
    else
      p Tag not found!
```